# Como imprimir en modo texto una página visualizada con QWebEngineView

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6, pyside

Usando PySide6 cargo una página html en un QWebEngineView y la imprimo con:

```
dialog = QPrintDialog(self)
if dialog.exec() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
    printer = dialog.printer()
    self.wvwInforme.print(printer)
```

Después de seleccionar la impresora con el botón buscar, pues no me la presenta en la lista de impresoras disponibles (esto no es un asunto grave) me imprime la página, pero como una imagen, no como texto, que sería lo propio.

Alguna sugerencia.

Y ya puestos, como imprimir una cabecera en el documento?

Nota. wvwInforme es el nombre del objeto QWebEngineView

Answer (score 0):

No hay forma ofrecida en la documentación oficial, y parece que no es simple de implementar. Pero puedo proponer algunas posibles vueltas al problema.

---

#### Pdfkit

[pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) es un modulo que depende de un exe llamado [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) que nos permite convertir html y css (ni idea si es compatible con javascript) en un archivo pdf.

---

#### Posible camino si querés ver la pagina como si apenas hubieses entrado

En este caso, pdfkit es la mejor solución, simplemente tenés que llamar a la función `pdfkit.from_url`, pasarle la url, el nombre del archivo y listo.

```
pdfkit.from_url(self.wvwInforme.url().toString(), "mipdf.pdf")
```

Nuevamente, puede que esto no sea compatible con javascript y tengas que hacer algún trabajo extra para lograr que funcione del todo.

---

#### Viendo la pagina en tiempo real (requiere conocimientos en html)

Aquí es donde se complica mucho la cosa.

**Tldr:** Aunque podemos ayudarnos de PySide6 y pdfkit para tener una buena base de la que empezar, se requiere mucho trabajo adicional para interpretar todos los detalles a tener en cuenta a la hora de imprimir la pagina.

###### Obteniendo el html

Para lograr el objetivo, tenemos que empezar con obtener el html en cuestión. Para eso, podemos usar `QWebEnginePage.toHtml`, muy indocumentado en PySide6, pero bien documentado en [Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#toHtml). La documentación indica:

> Asynchronous method to retrieve the page's content as HTML, enclosed
> in HTML and BODY tags. Upon successful completion, resultCallback is
> called with the page's content.

Que traducido sería:

> Método asincrónico para recuperar el contenido de la página como HTML,
> encerrado en etiquetas HTML y BODY. Una vez completado con éxito, se
> llama a resultCallback con el contenido de la página.

No se nada de c++, pero pude deducir que toHtml recibe de argumento una función que recibe el html ya obtenido.

###### Obteniendo recursos de la pagina

Las imagenes, las hojas de estilo (css), y otros recursos utilizados por la pagina, no se pueden obtener con toHtml. Para solucionar eso en el caso del css, tuve que recurrir a [una pregunta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63867084/12913664). En ella, una respuesta nos indica que podemos acceder a cada archivo css uniendo la ubicación de dicho con el link de la pagina (probablemente, esto se pueda hacer con todos los recursos).

Aquí vamos con otra librería, [bs4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), que nos ayuda a parsear html y, conociendo un poco de html, logramos acceder a la ubicación del css.

Podemos obtener el css usando otro modulo llamado [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

Posteriormente, podemos "incrustar" el css en el html usando la etiqueta style y metiendole el contenido del archivo.

###### Ejemplo

Ahora, pdfkit nos servirá de punto de partida para generar la pagina en forma de texto. Por supuesto, el siguiente ejemplo está incompleto, ya que una versión completa de esta idea llevaría mucho más tiempo y trabajo de crearse que no corresponde al proposito de esta respuesta.

Tener en cuenta que el texto de los campos de texto no son escritos en el pdf por este código.

```
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter
from os import startfile

from urllib.parse import urljoin
import pdfkit
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def endapp():
    # abrimos el pdf y cerramos todas las ventanas
    startfile("test.pdf")
    app.closeAllWindows()

def normal_print():
    view.print(printer)
    view.printFinished.connect(endapp)

def text_print():
    view.page().toHtml(read_page)

def read_page(content):
    url = view.url().toString()

    # indicamos donde está el exe requerido para generar los pdfs
    path_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)

    # Parseamos el html
    content = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

    # abrimos una sesión para que funcione más rapidamente
    with requests.session() as session:
        # Obtenemos todas las etiquetas link con el atributo rel="stylesheet"
        for css in content.select('link[rel="stylesheet"]'):
            css_url = urljoin(url, css.attrs["href"])

            tag = content.new_tag("style")
            tag.string = session.get(css_url).text #Obtenemos el css
            # reemplasamos la etiqueta link por style
            css.replace_with(tag)

    # quitamos los links por si genera problemas con el pdf
    for elem in content.select("a"):
        if elem.string:
            elem.replace_with(elem.string)

    # eliminamos todas las etiquetas que puedan hacer referencia
    # a un recurso externo o javascript
    for elem in content.select("[href], [src], script"):
        elem.extract()

    pdfkit.from_string(content.prettify(), "test.pdf", configuration=config)

    endapp()

app = QApplication([])

printer = QPrinter()
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf")

window = QWidget()
window.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

view = QWebEngineView()
view.load("https://www.minecraftjson.com/")

window.layout().addWidget(view)

button = QPushButton("Imprimir 'normal'")
button.clicked.connect(normal_print)
window.layout().addWidget(button)

button = QPushButton("Imprimir 'texto'")
button.clicked.connect(text_print)
window.layout().addWidget(button)

window.showMaximized()

app.exec()
```

Comment: Gracias Dante. Creo que de momento me voy a quedar con la solución 3 de mi autorespuesta, hasta que encuentre una forma sencilla de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a ver si soy capaz de poner en orden lo que he ido probando. Por si le sirve a alguien.

**1**
La función para imprimir el contenido del QWebEngineView (el self.wevInforme del código)

```
self.wevInforme.setZoomFactor(1)
# formato de documento apaisado
layout = QPageLayout(QPageSize.A4,
                     QPageLayout.Landscape,
                     QMarginsF(0, 0, 0, 0))
# generar pdf
self.wevInforme.page().printToPdf('informe.pdf', layout)
```

Esto funciona perfectamente, generando el pdf, puesto que solo tenemos el método printToPdf(). NO hay un print a secas.

**2**
He tratado de imprimir el documento con el código siguiente, pero no sale apaisado

```
# imprimir documento (no sale apaisado)
dialog = QPrintDialog(self)
if dialog.exec() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
    self.wevInforme.print(self.printer)
```

**3**
Y por último directo al os, donde solo sale bien si el Acrobat Reader tiene la selección de impresión en Automático.

```
# imprime bien si está seleccionado 'automático' en lector pdf
os.startfile('informe.pdf', "print")
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que os.startfile solo funciona en Windows

Comment: Sí, gracias. Es el ecosistema en el que corre